# How to position all dates on xAxis using recharts and stretch width on 100% in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

**1. I want to position on xAxis all dates (5 days every 3 hours) vertically ?**

**2. I want to stretch the graphic with a width of 100% on the screen and a height of 600 px ?**

```
<LineChart width={600} height={200} data={chartData}>
<Line type="monotone" dataKey="temp" stroke="#fc7f03" name="Temperature" unit=" °C"/>
<CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
<XAxis dataKey="date" tick={{fontSize: 10, fill: 'orange'}} tickFormatter={(unixTime) => moment(unixTime).format('DD.MM - HHч.')}/>
<YAxis />
<Tooltip />
</LineChart>
```

[image: screenshot]

[Examples on recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check their example you will find that they have a component
https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ResponsiveContainer

> ResponsiveContainer

You can import it from

> "recharts"

and then use it like in their example

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
        <LineChart
          width={500}
          height={300}
          data={data}
          margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 30,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 5,
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <XAxis dataKey="name" />
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <Legend />
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{ r: 8 }} />
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Also you can set settings for your XAxis.

Check docs here https://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis#tickCount

Comment: Do you know how to show values on the chart, and I can’t find how to display all data on xAxis..